# iPhone SMS messages stopped working with one contact

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

asking for a friend.  iPhone 13 Pro Max running IOS 17.1.  Strange symptoms started with one individual using SMS messages.  Other phone is a Samsung Galaxy.

Whenever the iPhone sends a message via SMS to the Samsung Galaxy, the message immediately disappears from the chat (history), is not delivered, and the phone brings up no errors.

Messages to other contacts via SMS work fine, and messages via iMessage also work.

Things we've tried so far:

- Restart iphone
- restart messages
- deleted and recreated the contact.
- checked with both individual to insure that no one was accidentally blocked.

Any ideas from you smart people who know weird edge cases on these protocols?

Comment: You have done some excellent diagnostic works; have you checked that the contact in question has a valid IMEI used at that time.